# Flutter: NotifyListeners does not seem to be working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextField in which I display a value. Then I have a FAB that allows me to add a value to a SQFlite database through an AlertDialog. When I click the add value button on the TextField it doesn't get updated, I have to reopen the app to see the changes.
Why? Am I doing something wrong?

In DBHelper class, methods to add a value and read all values:

```
Future create(Bmi bmi) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final id = await db.insert(tableBmi, bmi.toJson());
    log(bmi.toString());
    return bmi.copy(id: id);
  }

Future<List<Bmi>> readAllBmi() async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final orderBy = '${BmiFields.dateTime} DESC';
    final result = await db.query(tableBmi, orderBy: orderBy);
    return result.map((json) => Bmi.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Method in the BmiListViewModel to add and to read:

```
List<BmiViewModel> bmiVm = [];

  void readAllBmi() async {
    List<Bmi> bmiList = await DbHelper.instance.readAllBmi();
    loadingStatus = BmiLoadingStatus.loading;
    notifyListeners();
    this.bmiVm = bmiList.map((bmi) => BmiViewModel(bmi: bmi)).toList();
    if (this.bmiVm.isEmpty) {
      this.loadingStatus = BmiLoadingStatus.completed;
    } else {
      this.loadingStatus = BmiLoadingStatus.completed;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addNewBmi(Bmi bmi) async {
    log(bmi.value);
    await DbHelper.instance.create(bmi);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

main.dart:

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BmiListViewModel()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'BodyM',
        theme: ThemeData(
            canvasColor: Color(0xFF1C1C1E),
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme:
            GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
```

TextButton to add:

```
TextButton(
          child: Text("Add", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
          onPressed: () async {
            //here i create my bmi object
              await Provider.of<BmiListViewModel>(context, listen: false).addNewBmi(bmi);
            } else {
              //TODO
            }
          },
        ),
```

Container that contains the Text widget for displaying the value:

```
child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              if(bmiVm.toString() == '[]')
                Text('N/A', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white, fontSize: 80))
              else
                Text(bmiVm[0].valueBmi, style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white, fontSize: 80))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

bmiVm it's a List<'BmiViewModel'> create before the build method.

SOLUTION: I solved it. After addNewBmi method I have to call readAllBmi method to update the list and then notifyListeners() does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextButton(
      child: Text("Add", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
      onPressed: () async {
        //here i create my bmi object
          await Provider.of<BmiListViewModel>(context, listen: **true**).addNewBmi(bmi);
        } else {
          //TODO
        }
      },
    ),
```

> You have to listen to the state changes inorder to update UI.

Comment: You can try this, to rebuild the whole widget tree and see if it gives you the expected result. It will rebuild everything starting from MaterialApp and below.
However this seems to be an overkill. 
NotifyListeners should do the trick. Try to set debug points on them and to figure out why they don't work properly.